# recoll query history doesn´t seem to work

Tags: recoll

My system is Linux/Lubuntu 18.04.3.LTS, 64 bit. I´ve been using **recoll** for quite a while now.
I´ve updated to version 1.26.1 just now and noticed that clicking on "Show query history" doesn´t yield any results".
What could be the matter here? It used to work just fine.

The ~/.recoll/saved_queries folder is empty. So no query history is stored in the first place.

Tnx and cheers

UPDATE:

With the help of Jean-François Dockes, the Recoll developer, I could solve the problem:
You need to edit 
~/.config/Recoll.org/recoll.conf 
and add/change the following line with a text editor:

prefs\historysize=-1

In my case the value was set to "0", therefore no query history. With the value of "-1" it works just fine.

**screenshot settings for Recoll 1.23.7 + Xapian 1.4.5**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Note that in addition to the `prefs\historysize` setting,
if you have recoll version 1.26.0 or later
this can also be changed with the GUI
by going to "Preferences" -> "GUI configuration"
and setting "Maximum size of search history" to -1.

[image: Recoll - User Preferences]

This [feature was added October 4, 2019](https://framagit.org/medoc92/recoll/-/commit/8339559536c16c44359709f151c7077a1bab95df).

Comment: Hi Nathaniel. Thanks for your suggestion. Alas my GUI doesn´t have the respective option. See my original post: _"screenshot settings for Recoll 1.23.7 + Xapian 1.4.5"_.   So editing **~/.config/Recoll.org/recoll.conf** seems to be my only solution.

Comment: @Rosika Thanks for the reminder; I forgot that I'm using a PPA with a more recent version. I've added the version this feature was added to avoid confusion.

Comment: Thanks for the information. It´s all clear now.